# How to insert conditional formatting on excel charts

Tags: excel, charts

I wonder if it is possible to insert a conditional formatting on excel charts?. Because I want my chart to automatically change its fill color if its data source meets the passing grade or score.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check out [Conditional Formatting of Excel Charts](http://peltiertech.com/conditional-formatting-of-excel-charts/).

Answer (score 0):

This example VBA macro will turn all values in a line chart over 50. You could modify this with `if` statements to do custom conditional formatting

```
Sub ColourOver50()

 Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart
 Set s = cht.SeriesCollection(1)

 vals = s.Values

 For x = LBound(vals) To UBound(vals)
   If vals(x) > 50 Then
     With s.Points(x)
         .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
     End With
   End If
 Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tyler, Is that macro applicable on graphs?. How about multiple graphs? thanks!

Comment: ya just set cht to the chart you want it to. Do for each chart loops to apply to all charts